# How to reshape dataset

Tags: r

I have 2 colomns, the first one is the months and the second one is the value like that

```
month         windspeed
jan            2.5
jan            1.6
jan            4.5
feb            3.6
feb            3.5
feb            1.8
mar            4.2
mar            4.6
mar            3.8
```

I want to reshape that way

```
jan    feb    mar
2.5    3.6    4.2
1.6    3.5    4.6
4.5    1.8    3.8
```

Need help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unstack` from `base R`

```
 unstack(df1, windspeed~month)
 #  jan feb mar
 #1 2.5 3.6 4.2
 #2 1.6 3.5 4.6
 #3 4.5 1.8 3.8
```

Or create a sequence column grouped by 'month' and then use `dcast`

```
 library(reshape2)
 df2 <- transform(df1, indx=ave(seq_along(month), month, FUN=seq_along))
 dcast(df2, indx~month, value.var='windspeed')[-1]
 #  jan feb mar
 #1 2.5 3.6 4.2
 #2 1.6 3.5 4.6
 #3 4.5 1.8 3.8
```